# eclipse XML and SQL combined highlighting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp, syntax-highlighting

I have an XML file, inside CDATA I am having SQL content. I would like to highlight both XML and SQL syntax. Is there any eclipse editor which does this?

```
<query name="time">
<![CDATA[
         SELECT NOW() AS current_time;
]]>
</query>
```

Comment: It seems you need combined editor of SQL editor , XML editor. You can follow this : http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_an_editor_that_contains_another_editor%3F to create your own editor.